# XPath of span element

Tags: html, class, xpath

How can I get Xpath of the following element:

```html
<div class="datum">          
    <span>180 KM</span>
</div>
```

I need value "180 KM". I can't get it to work as this span element doesn't have any name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rely on the `class` of the parent `div`:

```
//div[@class="datum"]/span/text()
```